# Selenium / Pressing Radio Button not possible?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I try to press the following radio button "All Languages"

[image]

from this site

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1066456-d1083444-Reviews-or0-Sakura_Hotel_Hatagaya-Shibuya_T_Kanto.html#REVIEWS

using the following code

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0' 
  ua = UserAgent()
  userAgent = ua.random
  options = Options()
  # options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')   
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWebDriver = WebDriverWait (driver, 30)         
  
  link = f"https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1066456-d1083444-Reviews-or0-Sakura_Hotel_Hatagaya-Shibuya_T_Kanto.html#REVIEWS" 
  driver.get (link)  
  try:
    waitWebDriver.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( \
      (By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()       
  except TimeoutException as ex:
    print(f"{ex}")
  waitWebDriver.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( \
    (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='LanguageFilter_0']"))).click()       

  input("Press!")
  driver.quit()
```

But unfortunately, i get this error message:

```
$ python testScrape.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\david_defranza\testScrape.py", line 36, in <module>
    waitWebDriver.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( \
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Why is the button not clicked / found?
(the XPath i used works fine when inspecting in the chrome browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the xpath `//label[@for='LanguageFilter_0']` instead of `//input[@id='LanguageFilter_0']`,I tried it and it work's fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the website it's not

```
id='LanguageFilter_0
```

but

```
for="LanguageFilter_0"
```

If this modification did not work you can still do a look on the `class="Qukvo Vm _S"` and click on the first element.